# 自己回答をするには信用度が15必要？

Tags: サポート

ヘルプセンターの[「自分の質問に回答できますか?」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)に

> それを奨励するために、質問をすると必ずページの下部にチェックボックスがあります。信用度が 15 を超えていて、すでに回答を知っている場合は、[質問する] ページの下部にある [自分の質問に対して回答する] というチェックボックスをクリックします。自分の回答を入力し、質問と回答を一緒に送信します。

と書かれていました。自己回答をするには信用度が15必要なのでしょうか？　[権限の一覧](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)ページには載っていなかったので、気になっています。

もしそうなら、権限のひとつとして書かなくて良いのでしょうか。また、権限[「新規ユーザーの制限の解除」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user)の信用度10と閾値が異なるのは何故かもやや気になります。

Comment: [英語版のFAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17467/241919)より、必要な信用度は「今すぐ」自己回答するのためだけです…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

信用度が 15 必要なのは質問画面で直接自己回答する場合のみで、後から自己回答する分には信用度は必要無いそうです。このため権限が云々というのも問題ではありませんでした。

(Andrew T. さんに[コメント](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2846/%E8%87%AA%E5%B7%B1%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E3%82%92%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF%E4%BF%A1%E7%94%A8%E5%BA%A6%E3%81%8C15%E5%BF%85%E8%A6%81#comment2543_2846)で教えて頂きました。ありがとうございます。)